# Non integrable function

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

There are some functions whose indefinite integration is not possible. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Not exists or has no closed form formula?

Comment: If you mean "no elementary antiderivative", see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560679/how-to-tell-if-an-integral-can-be-integrated-has-an-elementary-anti-derivative

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons. For instance, [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) says that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f'$ has the mean value property. Therefore, a function that lacks that property cannot have an indefinite integral. That's the case, for instance, of the function$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\geqslant 0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: what about $$x[x\ge 0]+C=\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ where I've used the Iverson bracket?

Comment: @Masacroso I have no idea about what you mean by that.

Comment: what I wrote is equivalent to the [ramp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) more a constant. It represents the indefinite integral of $f$.

Comment: @Masacroso That function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: I know, but it represent the indefinite integration of $f$.

Comment: @Masacroso No it doesn't. An indefinite integral of the function $f$ that I mentioned would have to be a function $F$ such that $F'=f$. Your function doesn't have this property.

Comment: well, it depends on the definition of indefinite integral then. You are assuming that indefinite integral is equivalent to primitive, but I dont think its necessary.

Comment: @Masacroso Then tell us what's your definition.

Comment: a definition of indefinite integral could be a function such that when taking values it represent any definite integral of $f$, that is, if $F$ is an indefinite integral of $f$ then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=F(b)-F(a)$

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, it *could* be. But I must assume that the OP is using the standard definition of indefinite integral.